# Prevent Emacs from auto-reverting when the file size is over 10 GB

Tags: auto-revert-mode

How can I prevent Emacs from auto-reverting only when the file size is over 10 GB? I know that there's the *large-file-warning-threshold* option but it doesn't work for auto-reverting.

I'm dealing with a file that I frequently overwrite programmatically. It's a small file most of the time, but it sometimes becomes unexpectedly large so I'd like to prevent Emacs from freezing when I leave that file open.

Comment: Good question. If you do not get an acceptable answer here, consider filing an Emacs enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not using `auto-revert-tail-mode`, you might be able to just tell Emacs that if the file is too large, then the buffer is not "stale".  E.g. something like:

```
(defun my-not-too-big (&rest _)
  (or (not buffer-file-name)
      (let ((size (nth 7 (file-attributes buffer-file-name))))
        (< size 10000000000))))
(add-function :after-while buffer-stale-function
              #'my-not-too-big)
```

Rather than doing that globally, you could use `(add-function :after-while (local buffer-stale-function) #'my-not-too-big)` in a mode hook to only do that in the specific buffers you care about.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use `add-file-hook` to turn off `auto-revert-mode` for a file buffer that is larger than some limit.  This seems to work OK (tested minimally):

```el
(defvar my-max-auto-revert-size 1000000000
  "Do not auto-revert file buffers larger than this.")

(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (> (buffer-size) my-max-auto-revert-size)
              (setq global-auto-revert-ignore-buffer  t))))
```

(FWIW, I just added an enhancement request to make this kind of thing easier: Emacs [bug #25277](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25277).)